# Delete select menu after interaction Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have several buttons that each bring up a different select menu. I have been trying to figure out a way to delete a select menu after a selection is made so when the user clicks on the next buttons it stays clean with only the current menu showing.

I tried attaching a "submit" button to the menu's view that deletes the message but I get this error:

AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'message'

I also tried to edit the message after the interaction to add 'delete_after' but that didn't work either.

The menu is ephemeral and through research I see that you can't delete ephemeral messages due to the bot not seeing it. Is there any way around this?

```py
    class selectMenu(discord.ui.Select):
        def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(placeholder=placeholder, options=players, min_values=1, 
                         max_values=1)

        async def callback(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.defer()


    class selectMenuView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.add_item(selectMenu())

    *Tried this*
    @discord.ui.button(label="Cancel", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, 
                       row=3, disabled=False, emoji="✖️")
    async def cancel_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, 
                              interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.message.delete()
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you've tried? So far this is just the Select Menu and the Select Menu View. Perhaps add the button that you want to cause the select menu to be deleted?

Comment: I actually tried your delete button in the selectMenuView

Comment: @ESloman edited with the button in place

Comment: What you clarify exactly what it is you want to do? Just remove the select menus? Or do you want to remove the view completely?

Comment: My plan is to have the user to make their selection, process the data and then have the view be deleted like it was never there because above this message is an embed with 10 buttons and every button brings up a new select menu with different data attached to it.

My concern is that I don't want multiple selects sitting in the channel after their data is processed, it looks unprofessional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the messages are ephemeral, we can just edit the message content and set the `view` to `None` so that view disappears.

```py
class selectMenuView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.add_item(selectMenu())

    # a cancel button
    # will keep the message but remove the view and replace the text with "Cancelled"
    @discord.ui.button(label="Cancel", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, row=3, disabled=False, emoji="✖️")
    async def close_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        # if the message is
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Cancelled", view=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Submit", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, row=3, disabled=False)
    async def submit_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        # defer in case processing the selected data takes a while
        await interaction.response.defer()
        
        # do your data processing

        # use followup to edit the original message
        await interaction.followup.edit_message(interaction.message.id, content="Submitted data!", view=None)
```

The cancel callback uses `response` to edit the message. The submit callback uses the `followup` to edit the message with the message ID. Both work with ephemeral messages. The user can then press the "Dismiss this message" to get rid of the ephemeral message(s) they can see.

Comment: You should really start making youtube tutorials. There isn’t that much discord.py content out there and you can make a fortune. I have to keep you on retainer :)

Comment: is there a way to remove the view on timeout? I've tried to set the view of the original message to `None`  but it doesn't seem to update. Most comments I've read suggest refreshing the view, but I've not found a way to do that without `interaction` which isn't supplied as an arg for the `on_timeout()` builtin